# Google Sheets Parse Mathematical Expressions in Text Format

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, multiplication

Is there a way to take a text in a cell that says 5*5 and to parse to make the result 25... using QUERY function or any of the other built-in functions...?

Answer (score 2):

it would be like this:

```
=QUERY(SPLIT(B19, "*"), "select Col1*Col2 label Col1*Col2''")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

No. But if you have all such Mathematical expressions in a defined range(say,A5:A7), then you can use Find and Replace

FIND:

```
^
```

REPLACE:

```
=
```

Range:

```
Sheet1!A5:A7
```

Checkmark "Search using regular expressions". Click Replace all. Otherwise you'll need scripts.

Comment: I would want to do this systematically with a built in function... one solution I came up with was to use multiple cells.

Comment: @Code If you have a solution, Please post an answer

Answer (score 1):

**IF** you are **just** looking to parse simple mathematical expressions (+,-,x,/), then it can be done, but not in a single formula.

First, you can `split` the text based on your math operator, which will provide the numbers.  Then you can use `regexextract` to output the math operator, then use a nested `if` to perform the needed math operation on the numbers, based upon that operator.  You can hide the intermediate columns to put the answer next to the original.

[image]

Note that if you need to do more complex operations or operations on more than two numbers, this will not work.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution I could come with. Although I like how you actually used the multiply and add functions to make it cleaner looking. Like you said the limitation is to simple functions or this could really get out of hand... but in my application it was just a simple calculation.